# Trip sorter API

Tags: php, api

I've been given a task to complete. I need to create an API for a 'trip sorter'.
I've uploaded the PDF, which explains the task, to my webspace: [www.richardhedges.co.uk/Jobtask.pdf](http://www.richardhedges.co.uk/Jobtask.pdf)

I've no idea where to even begin! I think it's probably just the way it's worded that is putting me off, but I really am lost.

Can someone either get me started, or at least explain what needs to be done, in a way I can understand?

Thanks.

Comment: Your url does not work.  This also smells like homework.

Comment: Yeah sorry just fixed that.
It's a PHP web developer opportunity. The IT recruitment consultant told me I must complete this task. If I pass this I think I get an interview for the job.

Comment: So you are asking us to do your job interview for you?  Wow.

Comment: No no. I don't have a job interview yet, if I succeed with this I get a job interview. I'm merely asking someone to explain to me a little more (or write a bit of code to start me off) what it is exactly I have to do. As I don't understand it.

Comment: What don't you understand?  It seems pretty straightforward to me.  First create some classes or data structures to hold the data.  Create a way to "display" the trip and each card.  Write a method to figure out the itinerary given mixed up cards

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that the boarding passes are supposed to be out of order, and all the details are kept on the boarding pass. So where does the content (where the user is going from, and to) come from if the boarding pass is out of order. That'd be a starting point for me haha

Comment: Um, don't the boarding passes/cards contain that information?  But you are right - that is not explicit in the instructions.  Based on this pretty poorly written (grammatically, etc) exercise I'd pass on the opportunity.

Comment: Could you use a webcam or scanner to get the image of the boarding pass, then OCR the text from it and build up your list from that?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about that in the PDF. I phoned the IT consultant I've been speaking to and he said "All they want is to be able to see how you would go about coding something like this in this given situation". So, I'm still stuck.

Comment: Can you make the assumption that they will provide you a digital copy of the boarding ticket that you would be able to extract the starting and ending location of the trip leg the boarding card is for. That is the key information you need.

Comment: I can, however I'm still stuck on where to start. From reading that PDF, do I create a form they fill out, or do I simply set variables such as $from, $to, etc, that would be set by the server if the API were to be used for real.

Comment: According to the PDF, the API is internal, no server to client, no server to server communcation and according to these lines: `Write an API that lets you sort this kind of list and present back a description of how to complete your journey. For instance the API should be able to take an unordered set of boarding cards, provided in a format defined by you` - So you define what the boarding pass input list is, and you output the sorted version of the input list, using the format for boarding pass that you define. That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize my comment and add it as an answer, the steps you need to perform in your API
1. Define a boarding pass structure
2. Define a method that takes a collection of unsorted boarding passes and returns a sorted collection of boarding passes where the first pass starts at starting point and last pass ends at ending point.
Note - the collection of boarding passes should be in the format defined in step 1.

Comment: That makes so much sense now!! Thank you.